# Retrofit api call does not work

Tags: android, post, file-upload, retrofit

Api works fine with postman but does not work in retrofit.
Here is code:

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
@Multipart
@POST("listing/createListing")
Call<ResponseBody> pushData(@Header("Authorization") String auth,
                            @Part List<MultipartBody.Part> image,
                            @PartMap() Map<String, RequestBody>partMap);
List<MultipartBody.Part> images = new ArrayList<>();

for (int index = 0; index < list.size(); index++) {
RequestBody imageBody=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(filePath,file);
MultipartBody.Part part=MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image",fileName, imageBody);
images.add(part);
}


RequestBody titlePart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, "needs mowing preferably this Sunday");
        RequestBody equipmentPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, "0");

HashMap<String, RequestBody> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("title", titlePart);
        map.put("equipment", equipmentPart);

Call<ResponseBody> call = apiService.pushData("Bearer " + firebaseToken, images, map);
        call.enqueue()
```

Sometimes i get response code 413 sometimes 500.

Comment: whats "list" here ?

Comment: list of file @HeshanSandeepa

Comment: try post files one by one and see whether you get the same response

Comment: already tried same error